# Firebase Changing Data in Folders

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm organizing some folders in Firebase Database and I'd like to change the directories of some data, something like this:

> Before: Users/[IDs]/Economy/Items
>
> After: Economy/Users/[IDs]/Items

What can I do to get this? (I'm using javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has two databases, but neither of them has a concept called folders. Realtime Database (which I think you are referring to) has nodes, while Firestore has collections/documents.

In neither database there is an option to rename/move a node. The options is always to:

1. Read the data from its old location
2. Write it to its new location
3. Delete it from the old location.

In both Realtime Database and Firestore, you can do these operations in a single operation either as a transaction or as a multi-path update.

I recommend reading these previous questions on renaming/moving data:

- [Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+move+node)
- [Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5d%20move%20documents)

Comment: Yes, it's Realtime Database. I haven't found what I want, so I'm going to ask another question explaining it better.

Comment: Please don't post a new question. Instead click the `edit` link under your existing question above to clarify it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know it was possible, I'll do it next times

Comment: I just closed your repost. Please update the question here, so that the history is not lost. From reading the new question, my answer would remain the same though: you will need to write code to perform that operation.